# Reading flat file with uneven no. of columns

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

i have a csv file like this

```
**0, xyz, 20130301121212
1, 6997, 01234
2, 012345, 5678999, Y, 11, 20130301
2, 012345, 5678988, Y, 11, 20130301
1, 6647, 01234
2, 012345, 5678999, Y, 11, 20130301
2, 012345, 5678988, Y, 11, 20130301
9, 8**
```

rows with 0 are headers, 1's are for different stores and 2's are details records of products

rows with 2(as first column) are details of a store with row 1 (as first column)

can some one pls tell me how to group these rows with 2's with the corresponding 1's

Comment: Don't understand the last statement, "group these twos with 2's with the corresponding 1's. But I can tell you to first write an ETL to load data into table, better load the into 2 tables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything that you can share to make it easier to understand your problem? The best questions on StackOverflow include a clear problem, a summary of what you've tried so far, the outcome from what you tried, and what outcome you expected. All of these things will make your question clearer and easier to answer.

Comment: @ljh i meant how to group rows with 2 (as first col ) with rows having 1(as first col)  . if you observe the file above there are uneven no. of columns, how can i save that to a Data table. pls help.

Comment: Load your file to SQL Server is very easy, even the import wizard can do that. The problem is, how could you know "2" has relationship with just "1", but not "3", not "4". Once you have that relationship, you can have many different ways to get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using SQL Server and I can only provide general guidance:

1) Load file into database, whole row in column, add row number of line. Result will be something like (`rid` is row number):

```
rid rline
1   1, 6997, 01234
2   2, 012345, 5678999, Y, 11, 20130301
3   2, 012345, 5678988, Y, 11, 20130301
4   1, 6647, 01234
5   2, 012345, 5678999, Y, 11, 20130301
6   2, 012345, 5678988, Y, 11, 20130301
```

2) Use some SQL to get data in required shape. This means that you have to find first preceding row with 1 for every row with 2. Not tested:

```
select 
    csvdata.rline,
    csvdata.rid,
    (select rline from csvdata x where rline like '1,%' and x.rid < csvdata.rid order by x.rid desc limit 1) as TopRline
from 
    csvdata
where
    rline like '2,%' -- this will limit lines to only those with the detail
```

Hopefully, this will produce the following result with three columns:

```
rid rline                                 TopRline      
2   2, 012345, 5678999, Y, 11, 20130301   1, 6997, 01234
3   2, 012345, 5678988, Y, 11, 20130301   1, 6997, 01234
5   2, 012345, 5678999, Y, 11, 20130301   1, 6647, 01234
6   2, 012345, 5678988, Y, 11, 20130301   1, 6647, 01234
```

3) Split data into columns using some SQL function, (e.g. in PostgreSQL, `text_to_array()` would do this). Assuming result of 2 is stored in table temp, then something like:

```
select
  (string_to_array(rline,','))[1] as column1,
  (string_to_array(rline,','))[2] as column2,
  (string_to_array(rline,','))[3] as column3,
  (string_to_array(rline,','))[4] as column4,
  (string_to_array(rline,','))[5] as column5,
  (string_to_array(rline,','))[6] as column6,
  (string_to_array(TopRline,','))[1] as column1top,
  (string_to_array(TopRline,','))[2] as column2top,
  (string_to_array(TopRline,','))[3] as column3top,
from
  temp
```

4) Store data in any tables you want.

Answer (score 0):

Noting SSIS's difficulties with jagged CSVs, I would do a little bit of pre work in CMD run by SSIS so you can use the standard CSV functionality. Load to two separate tables and then just join the tables on the shared key column.

First split the rows from the jagged file into non jagged files. In windows something like below should do the trick.

`findstr /b "1," InputFile.txt > InputFileRow_1.txt`
`findstr /b "2," InputFile.txt > InputFileRow_2.txt`

Then load InputFileRow_1.txt and InputFileRow_2.txt using the SSIS standard CSV functionality into table InputFileRow_1 and InputFileRow_2 tables.

Finally, something like below to group.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM InputFileRow_1 ifr1
 INNER JOIN InputFileRow_2 ifr2
 ON ifr1.RowType2_ID = ifr2.RowType2_ID
```

*This method could be wasteful from an IO perspective depending on the distribution of row types in your file and the size of the file.